# Deleting a certain node in a linked list C programming

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I keep getting segmentation fault in my code but I don't know why. `int n` is the node that I will delete. so `listDeleteNth(new, 2)` would delete the 3 in the sequence.

1->2->3->4

1->2->4

```
typedef struct _node *Node;    
typedef struct _list *List;    

typedef struct _list {
    Node head; 
} list;

typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    Node next;  
} node;

void listDeleteNth (List l, int n) {
    Node current = l->head;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n-1) {
        current = current->next;    //node before deleted node.
    }
    Node temp = current->next;      //make temp the one to be deleted.

    if (current->next->next == NULL) {
        printf("you deleted the last node!\n"); //check if dlting lastnode
    } else {
        current->next = current->next->next;    //connect prev to after
    }
}
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Suppose there is only one node in your list.  Then this is guaranteed to fail (hint:  how can `current->next->next` possibly work if `current->next` is `NULL`?)

Comment: You have several issues in the code, the `i` parameter need to be increment, you need to think about the next 4 scenarios: empty list, 1 node list, the node to delete is the last one, the node to delete is not the first and not the last

Answer (score 0):

First, `i` and `n` neither are updated in the loop, so it will keep on moving to the next node and hence end up with a segmentation fault.

You may try to change the original loop:

```
while (i < n-1) {
    current = current->next;    //node before deleted node.
}
```

to the following:

```
while (i < n-1) {
    current = current->next;    //node before deleted node.
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, some edge cases need to be considered as well while I just simply point out the main issue